# right answer downvoted

Tags: discussion

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454858/regex-allow-for-the-occurrence-of-a-certain-character-up-to-one-time) I posted an answer which I think is the only that correctly answers the question. My answer got downvoted with comments unreleated to regular expressions (which leads me to think that he or she didn't understand my answer).

the question had no further activity, and I suspect the asker will not come back to close it. so, should I silently keep my downvotes? or is something else that could put some attention on this question (besides posting this in meta)?

Comment: After reading the question, I think yours is *not* "the only that correctly answers the question". In fact, it seems to unnecessarily complicate a straightforward issue. So am I allowed to downvote it?

Comment: @Jongware of course, but please comment.

Comment: Seems like a silly item, but your choice to abbreviate regex as RE is a bad decision.  While I don't do much in the regex world, I am unaware of any common usage of "RE" when referring regex.  Non-standard abbreviations are never a good idea because they usually can make your answer less understandable.

Comment: I also read the question, and it appears to me that **none** of the other answers are close to correct.  See my comment on the question.

Comment: I think this is actually the fault of the question not being specific enough and people thinking you overcomplicated your answer because they didn't completely understand the question. I do not think your answer 'deserves' so many downvotes. However, this is just bad luck and there's nothing meta can do about it (which is probably why this question is downvoted) since there are no strict rules for voting. Just move on.

Comment: I think it's bizarre that you have so many downvotes, but it also seems like a poorly expressed and ambiguous question.

Comment: I think you made an earnest effort on a bad question. I can't wrap my head around the question well enough to really judge well. I can imagine why some would down vote, but I probably wouldn't. But as others said; moving on is really the best thing to do :)

Comment: @fhdrsdg I find the question concise but with misleading examples. I couldn't help posting this, but I've got very useful comments. thank you all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing anyone can do. Just move on and find something else to answer.

If other people think that the answer is correct they will up-vote it.

However, have you considered that your answer *might* be wrong? You should review your answer and see if you've made a mistake.

Comment: yes, but obviously it still seems correct to me.

Comment: @pnuts - leaving an `@downvoter` comment is pretty pointless. There's little chance that they'll come back to check.

Comment: ok I'll try that.

Comment: Minor point of suggestion, @pnuts; I recommend such comments ignore the fact that there are down votes entirely, and simply ask something like, "If there's something I could improve here, I'm very open to thoughts." I suspect a lot of the positive responses to asking for reasons on down votes actually come from people who didn't down vote, and really, it's not the votes that are important - it's the quality of the content.