# What to do with a user who downvotes answer which seems correct?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, unfriendly-or-unkind

Recently, I've answered a specific question, with a request that could be answered fairly easy. At first the question seemed correct and well targeted, so I answered it, with good will. There was even a link of a git issue that he found close to an answer, but not the exactly what he was looking for.

Basically, in a web framework, he wanted to log requests, stating

`Result I'm expecting is: {id}/get_all for 1st request and {id}/get_last for 2nd request.`

Since it was enough to read the docs, I linked a couple of pages from the official docs saying that the docs contained what he was looking for and to check exactly on the docs which attribute fitted best to his needs. I also began my answer stating that he may not be able to achieve exactly what he was looking for without hacking the framework, but he could get close to what he wanted (there may be prefixes that would be part of the obtained path, e.g. `/prefix/1/get_all`).

I thought, this was more than enough for such an answer. I mean, if you don't read the docs (maybe he overlook the pages?) I gladly help you getting on the right path, but I'm not doing the work for you.

After a couple of hours, my answer gets downvoted, with a comment from the user asking for a code snippet (in his words) `relevant to his question`. I edited the question, providing an example of what he was looking for and where to edit his code. He then replies, stating that he clearly formed his question, asking for the regex (i.e. `{id}/get_all` and not `1/get_all`, which my answer could get). I pointed out in the comment that this was not written but he could reverse match it with a regex.

Now, I understand I probably shouldn't have answered the question since it was poorly written, but it seemed well written at first and the answer was easy, but he's not responding anymore and is keeping the downvote (which I find incorrect and unfair).

It is true that these are just points (-2 to be precise), but I feel I've been treated unfairly, because the answer told explicitly that it was going to get close to what he was looking for. He downvoted immediately my answer as if it was something off-topic. Also, his question was clear and my answer provided a solution to his problem, though he claims he clearly stated something different.

#### TL;DR

So, my question is: what should I do in such a case? I've been reading a post here that brought me to think to ask here.

[When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)
I've also looked on the stackoverflow's help page, without finding an answer. It's silly to be pissed off about such a little thing, I know, but I can't help ignoring it and going on, especially because OP downvoted immediately my answer.

Are flags the right approach in this case and possibly other similar ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downvoting my correct answer - Who or Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311915/downvoting-my-correct-answer-who-or-why)

Comment: If you're talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67587623/revisions), the downvote might be because of the meta-commentary itself...

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, it's that answer, but the downvote arrived with the first comment, then I edited the post and wrote about my philosophy on why I provided just the link (I was quite angry at the moment of writing it)

Comment: [Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388686/11682469)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Jeanne Dark yes and no. If there's no way of removing the downvote, I'll close this chapter and go on with my life, though it doesn't seem fair.

Comment: On one hand you state you probably shouldn't have answered it, then feel it is unfair you got a downvote for doing so. You can't have it both ways. Beyond that, what would happen here in Meta if everyone that got a downvote came here to complain about that singular vote.

Comment: Content rating on SO would be impossible if people were able to remove other people's votes they disagree with at will.

Comment: @charlietfl it looked like a correct question. I understand if someone is new and may not be the best at asking questions. Also, the question asked for a thing which I could easily answer, so I did. If I knew I would get the downvote because OP meant something different, I would have never answered.

Comment: @JeanneDark I know, though my answer is valid and would like for people to find it and not skip it because at first does not look relevant

Comment: What if someone else finds your Answer in a month and thinks that it is useful? On a side note, you should probably not underestimate the "meta effect" explained in [What is the meta effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: @Scratte I do hope so, though I personally tend to not look at the answers that have downvotes because I hope the community "filters" with downvotes irrelevant answers. I'll look at downvoted answers in a different way from now on.

Comment: Keep in mind that voting (up and down) isn't about correctness., As a matter of fact there is not a single feature within the SE network that that allows anyone to indicate if content is correct. Voting is about usefulness. I give you that a correct answer is more likely to be considered useful but it doesn't rule out that an answer is useful for every expert that evaluates the post. Instead of asking: why was my correct answer downvoted you better ask: How can I make my correct answer more useful.

Comment: Strangely enough, an answer that can never work correctly is occasionally 'useful', as long as it has comments explaining why it is flawed.  Users read the info and avoid that trap in future development:)

Comment: @MartinJames that was my point. I explicitly wrote that there is no simple solution without hacking the framework itself, but my answer could get him close (or even solve his problem if he's flexible enough to use regex). Finding it immediately not useful seems to me more like a preconception which is wrong.

Answer (score -8):

As discussed in the comments, the easiest solution is to live on and not care about the negative points, although the answer is indeed correct.

Though, it's not easy, but as stated in

[right answer downvoted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280837/right-answer-downvoted)

[Downvoting my correct answer - Who or Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311915/downvoting-my-correct-answer-who-or-why)

[Why shouldn't I assume I know who downvoted my post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388686/why-shouldnt-i-assume-i-know-who-downvoted-my-post)

one has to go on.

Thanks to the folks in the commentary for clearing it and making me understand.